# How to build/debug the Android head of an Uno platform app. under Linux?

Tags: android, linux, uno-platform

I have successfully installed the Uno platform templates, built and debug the Skia.Gtk head of my Uno  app on Ubuntu 20.04. But I'm stuck at the Android head for last couple days.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and have the following installed on my system:

1. dotnet 3.1 and dotnet 5.0 sdks
2. VS Code latest
3. Android Studio latest

What else do I need to do to build and debug the Android head of my app ??   I am unable to find any online guide for Uno platform Android heads on Linux.
[P.S. I have searched through the official Uno docs but could not get any help. I have also contemplated downloading and installing Xamarin.Android from source... (as Uno website suggests it depends on xamarin) ...  at  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android  but the page is reporting that the build for Ubuntu is currently failing.]

Comment: I would at least get a Hello World Android app working on Android Studio and/or Xamarin in your environment before trying a Uno Hello World app. As you are using a framework (Uno), on top of another framework (Xamarin) on top of Android's framework, its probably better to start at the lowest layer get the basics working before moving to the next layer.

Comment: Did you at least do: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-with-linux.html#using-ubuntu-2004-or-later and see: https://platform.uno/blog/a-piece-of-windows-10-is-now-running-on-webassembly-natively-on-ios-and-android/

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes ,  I have seen those docs. There is no mention of making Android head work under Linux.  Otherwise you are right. Lowest to upper levels is the ideal approach. I actually went straight to Uno because I reasoned that since  Android Studio and Xamarin.Android BOTH have official builds for Ubuntu why bother with their 'hello world".  It would be very odd if a  simple "hello world" wont work. 
Anyway , if no answer comes here,  I will start at lowest level tomorrow . Thanks for commenting.